# React - Como evitar algun metodo de arrays para que no salte el error cuando este es undefined?

Tags: reactjs, condiciones, fetch, undefined, metodos

Estoy tratando de hacer un fetch con mi propio archivo json.
Se que la primera vez el array esta vacio y por lo tanto no puedo hacer filter ni map.
Pero como puedo hacer para que se salte esta parte y que cuando si tenga contenido haga el metodo?

Para aclarar algo, el filter() esta puesto para poder ir recogiendo datos del archivo json, ya que fue la forma que se me ocurrio hacerlo.

```
const ProjectDetails = () => {
const [allWorks, setAllWorks] = useState([]);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
const { workId } = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    fetch('../src/assets/js/projects.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            setAllWorks(response);
            setIsLoading(false);
        })
}, [workId]);

let work = [];
!allWorks || !workId ? null : work.push(allWorks.filter(w => w.id === parseInt(workId)))

    return(
        <section className='project-details'>
            {isLoading && < Loading />}
            {!!work &&
                <div className='project-headerContainer'>
                    <img src={work[0][0].backdrop_path} alt="" />
                </div>
            }
        </section>
    )
}

export { ProjectDetails }
```

Sobre el codigo `work[0][0]` es debido a que la respuesta del json me llega en arrays y trato de meterme a eso, pero donde quiero igresar a otra cosa, por ej .id no me deja ya que me aparece como undefined

ACTUALIZACION

```
const ProjectDetails = () => {
const [allWorks, setAllWorks] = useState([]);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
const [project, setProject] = useState([])
const { workId } = useParams();



useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    fetch('../src/assets/js/projects.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            setAllWorks(response);
            setIsLoading(false);
        })
}, [workId]);

useEffect(() => {
    const work = [];
    work.push(allWorks.filter(w => w.id === parseInt(workId)))
    setProject(work)
},[allWorks])
```

gracias a la ayuda de agustin y a al simbolo ? pude hacerlo funcionar, no se si es lo adecuado pero estaria funcionando de momento.

```
<section className='project-details'>
            {isLoading && < Loading />}
            {project.length > 0 &&
            <>
                <div className='project-headerContainer' style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${project[0][0]?.backdrop_path})` }}>
                    <h1 className='project-title'>{ project[0][0]?.project_title }</h1>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

La verdad que no estoy probando el codigo por lo que no se si te va a funcionar asi o si tiene algun error.

Lo primero que haria es modificar el fetch y ponerlo en el `useEffect` con dependencia vacia para que se ejecute cuando se monta el componente. En él verifico que el id exista. Ahi seteas `allWorks`.

Para lo que sigue, primero convierto la variable `work` en un estado (lo llame `workArray`).

Luego, otro useEffect que se dispara cuando `allWorks` tenga contenido (es decir, se va a ejecutar luego del useEffect anterior, solo si `allWorks` tiene datos), lo que hago es definir un array temporal. Si existe workId filtro `allWorks` como lo venias haciendo y guardo en este array temporal.

Ahora guardo este array temporal haciendo `setWorkArray(tempArray)`

Finalmente, en el `html` solo imprimo el div si `workArray` tiene contenido

```js
const ProjectDetails = () => {
const [allWorks, setAllWorks] = useState([]);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
const { workId } = useParams();
const [workArray, setWorkArray] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
   if(workId){
    setIsLoading(true);

    fetch('../src/assets/js/projects.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            setAllWorks(response);
            setIsLoading(false);
        })
    }
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if(allWorks.lenght > 0){
   const tempArray = [];
   workId && tempArray.push(allWorks.filter(w => w.id === parseInt(workId)))
   setWorkArray(tempArray)
  }
}, [allWorks])

    return(
        <section className='project-details'>
            {isLoading && < Loading />}
            {workArray.length > 0 &&
                <div className='project-headerContainer'>
                    <img src={work[0][0].backdrop_path} alt="" />
                </div>
            }
        </section>
    )
}

export { ProjectDetails }
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta.

Probe de tu forma pero no me estaria pintando nada, entiendo que esta linea deberia modificarse
`<img src={work[0][0].backdrop_path} alt="" />`

Probe agregar un `console.log()` para ver si entraba al condicional
`workArray.length > 0 && <div>...` pero no estaria entrando. Tal vez no se renderiza nuevamente el componente

Comment: No vas a poder imprimir un console dentro del return(), pero podrias agregar un ``useEffect(() => {console.log(workArray)}, [workArray])`` para poder leer la variable cada vez que se modifique y asegurarte de lo que está pasando ahi dentro.